# How to change floating base type of model loaded from urdf file using pydrake?

Tags: drake

I am trying to load model from urdf file.

I can achieve this via `RigidBodyTree` [class](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.attic.multibody.rigid_body_tree.html?highlight=rigidbodytree#pydrake.attic.multibody.rigid_body_tree.RigidBodyTree.__init__):

```
rbtree = RigidBodyTree(file_name, floating_base_type)
```

Unfortunately, as it said at [pydrake.attic](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.attic.html) reference page, it will be deprecated soon.

I tried to add model using `pydrake.multibody.parsing.Parser` and `pydrake.multibody.plant`, but it seems that model is attached only with floating quaternion joint.

Is there a legal way of setting floating base type not with `attic` API?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Is it to use a floating roll-pitch-yaw joint rather than a quaternion joint?

Comment: Is it possible to use fixed or roll-pitch-yaw joint without `attic` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed base, the method you're looking for is [`MultibodyPlant.WeldFrames()`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.plant.html#pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant.WeldFrames). If `plant` is the `MultibodyPlant` object to which you've added your model, and the frame in your model named "my_base_frame" is supposed to be fixed to the world, the appropriate call would be:

```py
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName("my_base_frame"))
```

Note that this call should be made prior to calling `plant.Finalize()`.

I believe that `MultibodyPlant` currently does not support roll-pitch-yaw floating bases.

Comment: Actually I am interested in Spatial Inertia Matrix of system. Maybe there is a way of converting quaternion based model to roll-pitch-yaw based one?

Comment: The n x n system mass matrix is returned in velocity space v, not configuration space q so would be the same for either type of floating joint (assuming both would use angular velocity as their generalized velocities). Is that what you're looking for or is it the 6 x 6 instantaneous System spatial inertia (also independent of the floating orientation variables)?